# Can you index a PCAP file without loading it all into memory?

Tags: c++, pcap, pcapplusplus

I have to look at PCAPs that are quite large, around 40GB. What I'm doing right now is using PCAP++ to parse the PCAPs one at a time and process the data inside them. That data is placed into a buffer for it to be viewed. To save memory, I throw out the old data as you continue through the PCAP. This allows me to only use about 150MBs at a time. However, if the user wants to go back and view the data too far back, they can't because it's been thrown out.

Is there any way I can look at the PCAP file and go to the packets in which the data was stored and reprocess the data if the user wants to look back? It seems that if I want to get certain packets I would have to reload the file and look through it all again for each and every single section of data or split up the pcap file into a ton of bite size chunks.

Comment: I don't really know anything about PCAP++, but can you determine the raw packet boundaries in your PCAP file?  If so, you can store the offsets of these in a vector as you work your way forwards through the file and then, which you want to move back, you can re-read the raw packet data you need to decode the packet(s) in question.

Comment: @PaulSanders Correct me if I'm wrong, but what you are saying suggests that as I build the objects, store the ranges of packets that correspond to each object, and then when I need to reload an object, load the pcap file up again and only read that section of the pcap file. I'll try to see if that's possible but that leads me back to how can I get those certain packets.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm suggesting.  You just need to store the ranges, basically. 
 I don't know enough about PCAP++ to comment further I'm afraid, but it seems an approach worth exploring.

Comment: @PaulSanders Gotcha, I'll keep working on this, thanks for the help regardless :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out and short answer is no. PCAP++ doesn't support any functionality that could index, or mimic indexing, on a pcap file. I switched back to libpcap, (this also should work in windows with winpcap but I haven't tested it yet) in order to use a different library to help sort out what needed to be done. To do this properly you need to use file pointers that point to the critical packets (or all packets, depending on what you want) in your pcap file. Here's how it works:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
    pcap_t *pcap = pcap_open_offline((pcapPath.string()).c_str(), errbuf);
#else
    pcap_t *pcap = pcap_open_offline(pcapPath.c_str(), errbuf);
#endif

//-----------------------------
//... General Packet setup ...
//-----------------------------

vector<fpos_t*> pcapIndexer;
while(/*Get Next Packet*/){

    //Parse the packet and get required flag
    //to know if it is a critical packet

    if(/*Check some condition from the data*/){
        fpos_t* position;
#ifdef _MSC_VER
        pcap_fgetpos(pcap, position);
#else
        FILE* f = pcap_file(pcap);
        fgetpos(f, position);
#endif
        pcapIndexer.push_back(position);
    }
}
```

From the above code, you would go through each packet and depending on the data in the packet, you would add that file pointer to the vector of file pointers. Then once you need to load a packet, you create a new pcap_t pointer and use this:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
    pcap_fsetpos(pcap, pcapIndexer[x]);
#else
    FILE* f = pcap_file(pcap);
    fsetpos(f, pcapIndexer[x]);
#endif
```

You can then read as normal from that point. Note that you will have to run through the entire pcap file in order to fill out this vector of file pointers however if you use multi threading you can use some of the data that is in the earlier packets while the rest of the pcap file is being read through and added to the vector. This allows you to load in a select amount of data and then be able to jump back and forth to grab data from elsewhere in the pcap file. I hope this helps someone else in this situation.

Comment: Note that `pcap_fgetpos()` and `pcap_fsetpos()` aren't standard WinPcap/Npcap APIs; they're only in [Pat Marion's modified WinPcap](Pat Marion's modified WinPcap) - I'll look at whether it works to add it to libpcap.

Comment: @user16139739 Thanks, I haven't got a chance to test it on windows yet. I should have stated that, my bad :(